# alignment of pictures with CSS causes issue with Firefox/Windows but not with Firefox/linux

Tags: css, windows, linux, firefox, vertical-alignment

I have an oddly specific error concerning CSS, Firefox and Windows.

Let me explain: I use

```
vertical-align:sub;
```

... and it displays correctly with Firefox on Linux and IE on Windows but not with Firefox and Windows. I use the same version of Firefox on both Linux and Windows.

Some pictures of the problem (sorry for the inconvenience but, I can't post pictures or more than 2 links yet, so I have to do it like that):

http://www.mercuryproductions.de/kram/Errors.html

link to the page: http://www.sontag-consult.com/

If I fiddle around with the `vertical-align` I can get it to work with FF on Win, but it messes up the other combinations.

Comment: it seems that your your menu items are displayed correctly but not the image. can you check the background-position property for your images and try it to set the position of the images? If yo could provide us a working html/css link then it would be helpful to help you. Thanks

Comment: oops, sorry, while trying to please all the restrictions a newcomer has to face, I seemed to have deleted the link -> Link has been added.
The vertical-align is only meant for the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

**CSS**

Add this to your CSS file:

```
ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li
{
    margin:0 0 0 3px;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li:first-child
{
    margin-left:0;
}
ul li a
{
    padding:3px 8px;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
}
ul li a i
{
    margin:2px 5px 0 0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:20px;/* width of your img */
    height:15px;/* height of your img */
    background:url(/sprites.png) no-repeat;/*your img file here*/
}​
```

**HTML**

And this is what your HTML code should look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=""><i></i>Lang 1</a>
    </li><li>
        <a href=""><i></i>Lang 1</a>
    </li><li>
        <a href=""><i></i>Lang 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rJf7w/)**

BTW, it's probably recommended that you use [image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

---

### Updated:

**Solution 1 (IMG tags):**

**CSS**

```
ul li a img
{
    margin:2px 5px 0 0;
    border:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:20px;/* width of your img */
    height:15px;/* height of your img */
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=""><img src="/deutsch.png">Deutsch</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rJf7w/1/)**

**Solution 2 (w/ image sprites):**

**CSS**

```
ul li a i
{
    background:url(/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    margin:2px 5px 0 0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:20px;/* width of your img */
    height:15px;/* height of your img */
}

ul li a i.deutsch
{
    background-position:0 0;
}
```

**Solution 3 (w/o image sprites):**

**CSS**

```
ul li a i
{
    margin:2px 5px 0 0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:20px;/* width of your img */
    height:15px;/* height of your img */
}

ul li a i.deutsch
{
    background:url(/deutsch.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=""><i class="deutsch"></i>Deutsch</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks interesting, but will it work with multiple images? I guess I could put classes instead of just i there, but that seems kind of "hacky". I will try anyway.
I had image sprites in the past, but older browsers had problems with displaying them correctly, so I went back to single images. It was already risky to but that drop-down menu there.

Comment: Updated my answer. :) Maybe that helps.

Comment: Ok, Replace the vertical-align with margin-parameters works universally.
I had also hoped for a solution to why the functionality of Firefox is dependent on the OS, which I think is very strange.